# Parsing JSON data into specific format for chart.js

Tags: jquery, json, chart.js

I'm trying to use `Chart.js` to generate a pie chart using dynamically generated data. I'm having trouble getting the data in the right format, I think I'm close but I've been stuck for a while.

**I'm using ajax to get JSON data like this:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../helpdesk/getTicketsPerSubcat/' + startDate + '/' + endDate + '/' + activeLabel,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(result){
        var pieData = new Array();

        // populate array
        for (i in result) {
            var foo = {value: result[i].total, label: result[i].subcategory}
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(foo);
            pieData.push(jsonString);
        }
        console.log(pieData);
    }
});
```

**Which returns:**

```
["{"value":"2","label":"Disk Space"}", "{"value":"1","label":"Performance Issue"}"]
```

**This is what the documentation says the data needs to look like:**

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        label: "Yellow"
    }
]
```

I seem to have those extra quotes just inside the square brackets which must be what is causing an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`). Is `JSON.stringify()` the wrong function to be using? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Don't `JSON.stringify` the objects, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is `JSON.stringify()` the wrong function to be using?*

yes because a valid JSON is converted into a JSON string.

Instead just push the object you want to have in the array:

```
for (i in result) {
    var foo = {value: result[i].total, label: result[i].subcategory}
    pieData.push(foo);
}
```